# Angular CLI terminated

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I tried to run the angular6+ project using angular cli. The `ng serve` command successfully works for the first 2 times. Then it got failed and throws following exception in a terminal

```
 Date: 2019-07-22T09:32:45.493Z - Hash: 971b2b529ba3a299c693 - Time: 60343ms
5 unchanged chunks
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
 93% after chunk asset optimization SourceMapDevToolPlugin main.b7bbd1dd61be9e2eb871.js attach SourceMapng serve --configuration dev[15336]: c:\ws\src\util-inl.h:376: Assertion `!(n > 0) || (ret != nullptr)' failed.
 1: 00DA8A2E node::MakeCallback+3982
```

Any suggestion or solution?

Comment: Have you upgraded / downgraded your node version?

Comment: No, My current node version is 10.15.3

Comment: did we get the solution?

Comment: @VCody, yes, Kindly reinstall the node

Comment: @sanzmalz same version of node or the latest one